# What is the exact meaning of routes in Juniper tagged with @ and #

Tags: routing, router, juniper, juniper-junos

The routing table explains the meaning of these symbols as:

`@ = Routing Use Only, # = Forwarding Use Only
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both`

However, I am looking for more detailed meaning of what "Routing Use Only" and "Forwarding Use Only" mean. Those routes which can be used for forwarding should have been in the routing table as well. So why does "Forwarding Use Only exist". Can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Protocol-independent load balancing for Layer 3 VPNs allows the forwarding next hops of both the active route and alternative paths to be used for load balancing. Protocol-independent load balancing works in conjunction with Layer 3 VPNs. It supports the load balancing of VPN routes independently of the assigned route distinguisher. When protocol-independent load balancing is enabled, both routes to other PE routers and routes to directly connected CE routers are load-balanced.

When load-balancing information is created for a given route, the active path is marked as `Routing Use Only` in the output of the `show route table` command.

If the route is inactive, the reason for its current state is indicated, where `Forwarding use only` indicates that the Path is only available for forwarding purposes. That is all i could find on **Forwarding Use Only**.

Source: https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/usage-guidelines/vpns-configuring-protocol-independent-load-balancing-in-layer-3-vpns.html

https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/command-summary/show-route-extensive.html